# Are these two phrases predicative complements?

Tags: complements

> “I was born a son of a bitch and I’m going to die a son of a
>   bitch.”
>  (One Hundred Years of Solitude, tr. by Gregory Rabassa)

It seems like ‘was born’ and ‘am going to die’ are [Catenative Verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb); both the ‘a son of a bitch’ are [predicative complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_complement). Is this the right parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right on the predicative complements.

Formally I suppose there's nothing wrong with calling the constructions *be born* and *be going to die* catenative. But I don't think you'll find many grammarians following that use. *Be* and *be going to*, like *have* and *have to* and *be able to* and the modals, are regarded as *auxiliary verbs*: what they contribute to a construction isn't lexical meaning but grammatical tense and aspect.

And there are restrictions on extracting an auxiliary from a chain. Consider, for instance, rewriting a catena as a pseudo-cleft. You can say:

> He admitted stealing the picture → What he admitted was stealing the picture.

But you can't say

> You've killed him! → <sup>✲</sup>What you have is killed him.
>   I'm going to die a son of a bitch → <sup>✲</sup>What I am is going to die a son of a bitch.