# Is 'as' missing in 'he died a virgin'?

Tags: sentence-construction, as

'He died a virgin.'

Or, 'he died as a virgin'?

Why 'as' is not used in the first sentence? Is is grammatically correct to use the first sentence?

I remember in America's got Talent a contestant said to judges that 'Issac Newton died a virgin. And.....'. Out of respect to him I opt to not use his name in the question sentences.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: [Are these two phrases predicative complements?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/8903/41273) and [Die a Noun: died a hero](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/270139/41273)

Comment: At first glance I just thought ***as*** was "optional" in the cited context. Then I realised that it *shouldn't* be included, because it might be misunderstood as meaning *He died **in the way virgins die*** - even though he wasn't *actually* a virgin himself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Died" can have a "subject-verb-complement" structure.  And the complement can be a noun, or an adjective or a prepositional phrase.  "He died a virgin" has the same structure as "He was a virgin".  The verb "died" is a linking verb in these sentences.

I know that "a virgin" isn't a direct object, because the passive form *"A virgin was died by him" is completely ungrammatical.

But constructions with adjectives are correct "He died young", for example. Most verbs can't be used as linking verbs like this, and "die" is not normally used this way.

Comment: I'd call "died" an intransitive verb, not a linking verb. A linking verb usually requires a complement to maintain its meaning, but if we wrote "he died", then the verb would have the same meaning. (Writing "he was", however, would make little sense unless a complement were inferred.)

Comment: Yes, usually it is an intransitive verb,  but when used with a complement it is a linking verb.  If you don't think "a virgin" is a nominal complement, (describing the subject) then what is it?

Comment: You could compare "He came home a hero", "He left a free man", "He was born a slave", even with an adjective: "He came back emptyhanded", "he died happy", "he drove drunk".

Comment: @JamesK It is indeed a nominal subject complement, but it follows an intransitive (not linking) verb, as in StuartF's examples. A subject complement can even follow a transitive verb (though it is rare): "After completing rehab, I lived the rest of my life a changed man."

Comment: @MarclnManhattan Is there any list of common verbs which can be used like that.

Comment: @JamesK in ur answer you said "died can have a subject-verb-complement. And the complement can be a noun, or an adjective or a prepositional phrase" so can you please give me a few examples based on prepositional phrase complement?

Comment: "He died as a virgin"